# Laravel git ignoring images uploaded to storage

Tags: laravel, github, gitignore, git-commit

I'm running into an issue which i haven't been able to solve yet.

I was working on a laravel project and than moved this project folder to a newer version of MAMP. So far so good, everything was working fine. I just copied all the folders and files and all was good until i logged in to my laravel application on localhost and uploaded some images.

I know i can do this on my host but i like to work on localhost to add content and than push it to my prod env. Anyway, after i uploaded some images and did a git add . and commit it didnt add my uploaded images, on phpstorm they also turn out red in the storage/app/public/images folder.

On my previous mamp version everything used to work fine.

Stuff I have already tried:

I tried deleting the symlink storage folder and make a new link, didn't help.
I tried deleting the storage folder from gitignore, also didn't help.

My gitignore file looks like this:

```
/node_modules
/vendor
/public/hot
/public/storage
/storage/*.key
.env
.env.backup
.phpunit.result.cache
Homestead.json
Homestead.yaml
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log
/config/database.php
/public/sitemap.xml
```

When i login on my prod env and i upload images, they turn up fine, but i prefer sometimes to work from localhost to write content and push it to env.

I have also tried to:
git check-ignore -v -- path/to/file

To check why the file (image) is being ignored but it doesnt return anything.

I got one time a message with: Fatal: pathspec ... is beyond a symbolic link.

I hope someone can push me into the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: possibly  youhave a .gitignore file in `storage/app` https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/master/storage/app

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Yes, there is but the file is empty.